# Nested loop inner join with index lookup and filter is slow

Tags: sql, mysql, join, sql-execution-plan

I have this query I'm running in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    library AS l
    JOIN plays AS p ON p.user_id = l.user_id AND
    l.path = p.path
WHERE
    l.user_id = 20977 AND
    p.time >= '2022-10-17';
```

When EXPLAIN ANALYZE is run:

```
| -> Aggregate: count(0)  (cost=1085653.55 rows=6692) (actual time=12576.265..12576.266 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=1084984.37 rows=6692) (actual time=40.604..12566.569 rows=56757 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on l using user_id_2 (user_id=20977)  (cost=116747.95 rows=106784) (actual time=13.153..3783.204 rows=59631 loops=1)
        -> Filter: ((p.user_id = 20977) and (p.`time` >= TIMESTAMP'2022-10-17 00:00:00'))  (cost=8.24 rows=0) (actual time=0.135..0.147 rows=1 loops=59631)
            -> Index lookup on p using path (path=l.`path`)  (cost=8.24 rows=8) (actual time=0.090..0.146 rows=1 loops=59631)
 |
1 row in set (12.76 sec)
```

I obviously want to make this faster!

#### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE `library` (
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `db_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `plays` (
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `play_id` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE `library`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id_loc` (`user_id`,`name`,`path`(191)),
  ADD KEY `edited` (`edited`),
  ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
  ADD KEY `title` (`title`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  ADD INDEX `user_id_by_title` (`user_id`, `title`);

ALTER TABLE `plays`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`play_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`name`,`path`(255)),
  ADD KEY `user_id_2` (`user_id`,`name`),
  ADD KEY `time` (`time`),
  ADD KEY `path` (`path`),
  ADD KEY `user_id_3` (`user_id`,`name`,`path`,`time`);
```

It looks like the killer is the looping over 59631 rows.

Would an index on `(user_id, time)` make it faster?

Interestingly, the `user_id_2` index is actually an index on `(user_id, title)`, rather than the plain `user_id` index. I'm not sure why `user_id_2` is chosen given `title` isn't used in the query.

Comment: Your code has some errors (`ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table library`). I can't run it to try to reproduce the issue. This makes me doubt if _any_ of the code is relevant to your query. Please post the _actual_ code you're having trouble with. Or better yet, make a dbfiddle.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sorry. Truth is the column name is `id`. However I posted a previous question on SO where a lot of feedback was about column naming, so I tried to find and replace the column name, but I missed one out. I'll fix that so it's all `user_id` now.

Comment: @TheImpaler What do you mean by malformed? I assumed you meant some sort of syntax error, but it runs ok for me (MySQL). However your mention of "silently converts" makes me think you mean it's not optimal, rather than malformed. So what do you mean by fixing it? The criteria appears as it should - the rows from the `plays` table should only be brought back having `p.time >= '2022-10-17'`. Do you mean just the fact it should not be a `LEFT JOIN` because of the implicit criteria? Agree - but I was just trying to use the query I have - if this is the cause of the slowdown - great!

Comment: @DanGravell Yes, the `LEFT` in `LEFT JOIN` shouldn't be there. It misguides your analysis. From the optimizer's perspective there are big differences between an outer join (less options to optimize) and an inner join (more avenues for optimization).

Comment: The join issue doesn't confuse MySQL much. It automatically optimizes it as an inner join when it detects that the condition makes the left outer join function as an inner join. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks - I updated the query and the EXPLAIN ANALYZE. There appears no obvious difference in time spent.

Comment: Is `library.name` "album title" and `plays.name` like "song title"?  That is they are not related?

Comment: Are there 6692 rows in `library` and 59631 in `plays`?  Or am I misreading the ANALYZE?

Comment: @RickJames _Is library.name "album title" and plays.name like "song title"? That is they are not related?_ - No, `name` is another column that doesn't describe itself very well, but basically it refers to the source of the row in `library`. When rows are added to `library` it comes from a source called `name`.

Comment: _Are there 6692 rows in library and 59631 in plays_ yes, sounds pretty typical. `library` is a music track, `plays` is the play of a music track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your query and tried a different index in each table.

```
ALTER TABLE library ADD KEY bk1 (user_id, path); 

ALTER TABLE plays ADD KEY bk2 (user_id, path, time); 

EXPLAIN SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    library AS l USE INDEX (bk1)
    JOIN plays AS p USE INDEX (bk2)
      ON p.user_id = l.user_id 
      AND l.path = p.path
WHERE
    l.user_id = 20977 
    AND p.time >= '2022-10-17';

+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | NULL       | ref  | bk1           | bk1  | 4       | const             |    1 |   100.00 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ref  | bk2           | bk2  | 2056    | const,test.l.path |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

The note "Using index" in each row of the EXPLAIN report shows that it's getting the benefit of a [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) for both tables.

I didn't use prefix index syntax, because that would spoil the covering index optimization. It's not necessary to use prefix indexes for this example on modern MySQL versions because they default to an InnoDB row format that supports 3072-byte indexes instead of the old MySQL that only supported 768-byte indexes by default.

In my test, I had zero rows in the tables I tested, so I had to use an index hint to make the optimizer choose my new indexes. In a table with a substantial number of rows, the optimizer might choose the new indexes on its own.

Comment: I'm creating the indexes to test now. Does this work because the join uses an index with the same prefix between the two new indexes - `(user_id, path, ...)` - and then the `bk2` is ordered by `time` so that the time comparison is very fast?

Comment: The covering index optimization is simply that the two indexes contain all the columns needed for the query, so MySQL can skip reading rows from the table at all. The order of the columns in my indexes is important. Columns used for equality conditions are first (leftmost), then one column for a range condition is next, then more columns as needed for the covering index.

Comment: You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: Thanks - the telephone book analogy describes well how I understand this, but I hadn't thought about also including the other columns needed for the query. What if there's a second column after the time that were a range query, e.g. duration? Would that mandate another index, like `ALTER TABLE plays ADD KEY bk3 (user_id, path, duration);` and the query would be able to easily shift from bk2 to bk3 because it already has the `(user_id, path)` 'prefix'?

Comment: Yes, ideally the optimizer will choose the best index for each query. You may need multiple indexes that have some columns in common, to support different queries. Unfortunately, in practice sometimes the optimizer gets confused about indexes with common leading columns, and picks the wrong one. So we need to use index hint syntax sometimes (I try to avoid it unless absolutely necessary).

Comment: The index (user_id, path, time) is probably the most efficient one. @BillKarwin Do you know if it's possible to show the "cost" of the plan in MySQL?

Comment: I added the indexes, but the query still takes over 1s (I don't know what I was expecting, but, say, under 0.5s). https://explain.depesz.com/s/6CaQ - I can't see an obvious fix because it appears to be performing the join between `library` and `plays` correctly filtering by `user_id`, and that just leads to a lot of rows. Is there a better way of ordering the criteria?

Comment: That site is a PostgreSQL query analyzer. Are you using PostgreSQL or MySQL? You posted your question tagged MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin -- In my experience...  When given `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)`, the optimizer will often pick the former even though the latter would clearly be better.  So I often suggest DROPping the shorter.

Comment: @RickJames, Yeah, the optimizer thinks that a more compact index is better, I assume because it estimates a lower total cost for loading fewer pages into buffer pool. I think it underestimates the benefit of using a covering index.

Comment: @BillKarwin Ooops, sorry yes I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames ... but in this case the covering indexes are being used, aren't they?

Comment: (as seen in the depesz link above - the `using user_id_path` and `using user_id_path_time` text in the _Stats_ tab).

Comment: @TheImpaler, The current version of MySQL supports tree-format output, which appears to be similar to PostgreSQL EXPLAIN ANALYZE. But MySQL obviously is a different implementation, so we have no assurance that EXPLAIN actually works the same as PostgreSQL. So far, MySQL has not documented how to interpret the information in their tree-format output or json-format output. They show examples, but don't explain how to read it.

Comment: The [_Optimizer Trace_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#optimizer_trace) (since 5.6.3) provides an different detailed look -- including which plans that were investigated and rejected.  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` dates only from 8.0.18; it seems to exactly count rows and precisely time (sub-millisecond) each phase of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

DROP these, they in the way and/or redundant:

```
l: `user_id` (`user_id`),
p: `user_id` (`user_id`,`name`,`path`(255)),
p: `user_id_2` (`user_id`,`name`),
```

Add these:

```
l:  INDEX(user_id,  path)
p:  INDEX(user_id,  path, time)
p:  INDEX(user_id,  time, path)   -- see below
```

Change  (MySQL 5.7/8.0 no longer needs the prefix kludge):

```
l:  `user_id_loc` (`user_id`,`name`,`path`)  -- tossing 191
```

Try to avoid testing columns from different table in `WHERE`.

First I saw

```
    WHERE  l.user_id = 20977
      AND  p.time >= '2022-10-17';
```

and assumed that was the crux of the problem.  But then I saw that you did not have `INDEX(user_id, time)` on `p` *and* that the tables are joined [partially] on `user_id`.

Suggest (to avoid my confusion) that you make this change:

```
    WHERE  l.user_id = 20977   -- >
    WHERE  p.user_id = 20977
```

The Optimizer *should* be smart enough to realize that, then use

```
p:  INDEX(user_id,  time, path)   -- as mentioned above
```

But, once you have done that, the query collapses to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, path)
    FROM plays
    WHERE  user_id = 20977
      AND  time >= '2022-10-17';
```

I think that it will say "Covering index skip scan for deduplication" to indicate that it is not actually scanning all 60K rows in `plays`, but hopping through the index!

However, if there are "plays" that do not have a corresponding entry in "library", then the count will be high by the number of missing user-play combos.

When the table has **both** `INDEX(a), INDEX(a,b)`.:

- When a query needs just `(a)`, then *either* index will work.
- When a query needs `(a,b)`, the Optimizer is likely to pick `(a)` because it is smaller while failing to realize that the bigger index would be better.

For that reason, I suggested some of the `DROPs`.

The other reason for `DROPs` is to get rid of "prefix" indexing (`path(255)`) which is either counterproductive and/or no longer necessary.

Comment: _DROP these_ - but these indexes are used by other queries... so I can't really just drop them. I'll go ahead and test your other suggestions though.

Comment: I tried this, but it looks like it's not using the correct indexes (I removed the `USE INDEX` statements suggested by @BillKarwin because of the additional index you suggested above - I wasn't sure where this should be used). As a result it takes almost 7s - https://explain.depesz.com/s/htQ1

Comment: @DanGravell - I addressed both of your comments in an addition to my Answer.

Comment: thanks. As I said, I can't drop them, because they are required by other queries. I tried with USE INDEX again but I'm not sure where you're suggesting `INDEX(user_id,  time, path)` should be used - I can only see the FROM and JOIN statements as possible places.

Comment: I also tried the alternative query - `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT...` - but this took double the time. It appeared to only use the shortest `user_id` index. I changed it to use the `INDEX(user_id,  time, path)` but that still takes 4s.